# pagespeed url parameter issue

Tags: javascript, pagespeed

I developed a Magento extension which includes js file into head. I included also some parameters in file name that are needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/.../script.js?v=2.4.3__baseUrl=www.domain.com/en/__anotherparameter=value__.pagespeed.ce.PlJFCkYUf0.js"></script>
```

The problem is because Pagespeed will change url to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/.../script.js,qv=2.4.3__baseUrl=www.domain.com,P2Fen,P2F__anotherparameter=value__.pagespeed.ce.PlJFCkYUf0.js"></script>
```

I already replaces & with __ because it replaces also &. Now I am having also problem with "/". Is there any way to decode replaced characters with javascript? Or at least some list of characters that pagespeed replaces so I can manually replace it with my own set of characters and then later decode this back?

Since this extension will be installed on other sites, I don't have any influence to pagespeed settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternate method of loading this script. My favorite is with jQuery:

```
jQuery.getScript("/path/to/myscript.js", function(data, status, jqxhr) {
    /* 
       do something now that the script is loaded and code has been executed
    */  
});
```

From http://davidwalsh.name/loading-scripts-jquery

Comment: Thank you but I prefer to keep script inside head for some other reasons.

Comment: Well you can execute this script in the header just the same, inside <script> tags.